# Is there the function to compute the sum of only hours from the format : "H:M:S"

Tags: r

The objective of my work is to delete dates where i can’t get at least one temperature in each hour (1h, 2h, 3h,..... 23h)

- I use to compute the sum of hour by id and by date
- Then i will delete rows by using filter

```
sum_heure=tab[,list(h=sum(hour(as.POSIXct(tab$heure1,format="%H:%M:%S")))),by=list(id,date1)]

sub_Test_Heure=filter(sum_heure,h ==276)
```

This is an example of my data frame:

```
id<- c("130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f","130f"
       ,"138g","138g","138g")
date1 <- c("01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ", "01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 "
           ,"01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 "
           ,"01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 "
           ,"01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 ","01/01/2017 "
           ,"02/01/2017 ","02/01/2017 ","02/01/2017 ")
temperature <- c(15,16,20,18,26,18,24,24,28,25,27,23,26,19,28,17,26,34,16,18,17,13,28,29,25,27,29,16,19,17,19,26,27,30,34,38,36,35,39,28,26,29,27,24,32,30,23,37,29,32,29,27,29)
heure1<-c("00:04:00","00:14:00","00:30:00","00:50:00","01:04:00","01:24:00","01:34:00","01:50:00","02:00:00","02:14:00","02:34:00","02:54:00","03:10:00","03:20:00","03:54:00","04:34:00","04:59:00","05:04:00","06:00:00","06:20:00","06:44:00","07:14:00","07:34:00","08:04:00","08:44:00","09:00:00","10:04:00"
          ,"10:04:00","10:34:00","10:54:00","11:24:00","12:04:00","13:04:00","14:04:00","14:49:00","15:00:00","15:34:00","16:00:00","16:44:00","17:14:00","17:44:00","18:25:00","19:30:00","20:04:00","20:45:00","21:10:00","22:04:00","22:47:00","23:12:00","23:50:00","00:50:00","01:30:00","22:10:00")
tab <- cbind(id,date1,heure1,  temperature)
```

Comment: Note that what you have as `tab` is a matrix, not a data frame, and it doesn't have names. `tab$heure1` throws an error for that reason. Where have you loaded `hour` from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the full dataset column (`tab$heure1`), specify only the unquoted column name (assuming that it is a `data.table` (note that `cbind` converts to `matrix.)

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(tab)[, .(h = sum(hour(as.POSIXct(heure1, format = "%H:%M:%S")))), 
           .(id, date1)]
#     id       date1   h
#1: 130f 01/01/2017  479
#2: 138g 02/01/2017   23
```

Or using `hms`

```
setDT(tab)[, .(h = sum(hms(heure1)@hour)), .(id, date1)]
```

#### data

```
tab <- data.frame(id, date1, heure1, temperature)
```

Comment: @EmmanuelGNOFAM  You can just do a subset `setDT(tab)[, .(h = sum(hms(heure1)@hour)), .(id, date1)][h > 276]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have read your data as dataframe (and not matrix), we can `unite` `date1` and `heure1` column convert them to `datetime`, extract `hour` and `date` from `datetime`, select the date which has all hours of the day present (0:23) `group_by` `id` and `date` and take `sum` of `hour` for each date.

```
library(dplyr)

tab %>%
  tidyr::unite(datetime, date1, heure1, sep = "") %>%
  mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %T", tz = "UTC"), 
         date = as.Date(datetime), hour = as.integer(format(datetime, "%H"))) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  filter(all(0:23 %in% hour)) %>%
  group_by(id, date) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(hour, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(total >= 276)

#  id    date       total
# <fct> <date>     <int>
#1 130f  2017-01-01   479
```

Comment: Thanks. yes I want to sum the hours and keep in the dataset the lines that allowed to have a sum greater than or equal to 276

Comment: @EmmanuelGNOFAM I added a line `filter(total >= 276)`. You need to assign the output of this to a new object to see the change.

Comment: thanks. i delete my question because i find the solution.